# Phaser - TileSprite has green lines?

Tags: phaser-framework

EDIT: Resolved by updating phaser from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6

I want a repeating background, so I tried to use a tile sprite of a 40x40 image. It works and scrolls fine aside from the green lines:

[image]

This is the code I'm using for it:

```
this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0, 0, this.game.world.width, this.game.world.height, 'space');
this.background.autoScroll(0, 30);
```

How do I get rid of those and the padding to the right and bottom of it?

Comment: Any chance you can get a working example up on js bin or some other site?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at your sprite to see if it has any green lines, or if it bumps up against anything with green, if it's part of a spritesheet. Phaser will grab pixels from the sides in certain cases.

Comment: I got it by updating my version of Phaser. Thanks anyway! :)